# What is the safest way to empty a directory in *nix?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I'm scared that one day, I'm going to put a space or miss out something in the command I currently use:

```
rm -rf ./*
```

Is there a safer way of emptying the current directory's contents?

Comment: Good Unix distros doe not protect you from yourself, and quality hackers prefer it that way.

Comment: I wish such a comment  could be downvoted.
Protection against mistakes is good, as long as it does not create stupid overhead ruining your productivity.

e.g.  I always use root, because I hate having to put "stupid sudo" before every command I type...  but OTOH, I aliased my mv & rm to always have confirmations by default.

Good unix distros just let you do things the way you like it.  Basic protections against stupid typos is great, as long as it isn't silent, and produces a clear error message when you mistakenly ask to empty your / directory.

Comment: And to answer the question, I personally am used to first type "rm <destination>", _then_ read it again, double check, and add the final "-rf" at the end of the line.
It might seem stupid, or utterly slow, but I don't use it dozens of times a day, and whatever the conditions, I'll ALWAYS be afraid of accidentally hitting enter while typing.  This is the main reason why I don't type the -r parameter before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The safest way is to sit on your hands before pressing Enter.

That aside, you could create an alias like this one (for Bash)

```
alias rm="pwd;read;rm"
```

That will show you your directory, wait for an enter press and then remove what you specified with the proper flags. You can cancel by pressing ^C instead of Enter.

Comment: That's nasty; it encourages you to assume that you'll be given a second chance with the rm command.  Wait until you move to another machine or are logged in as another user, and *bam*...

Comment: It would be better to do something along the lines of alias alias delete="..."

Comment: Yes, using a different name is probably a better idea. But still, nothing will replace proper care (you can get so accustomed to press enter twice that it'll do you no good when you most needed it)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a safer way: use `ls` first to list the files that will be affected, then use command-line history or history substitution to change the `ls` to `rm` and execute the command again after you are convinced the correct files will be operated on.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be really safe, you could create a simple alias or shell script like:

mv $1 ~/.recycle/

This would just move your stuff to a .recycle folder (hello, Windows!).

Then set up a cron job to do rm -rf on stuff in that folder that is older than a week.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a reasonable way:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \! -name . -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

and it will also take care of hidden files and directories. The slash isn't required after the dot and this then will also eliminate the possible accident of typing `. /`.

Now if you are worried what it will delete, just change it into

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \! -name . -print  | less
```

And look at the list. Now you can put it into a function:

```
function enum_files { find . -maxdepth 1 \! -name . "$@"; }
```

And now your remove is safe:

```
enum_files | less                     # view the files
enum_files -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf  # remove the files
```

If you are not in the habit of having embedded new-lines in filenames, you can omit the `-print0` and `-0` parameters. But i would use them, just in case :)

Comment: You don't need the pipe: `find -mindepth 1 -print -delete` (Remove the `-delete` for testing and note that I've changed `maxdepth` to `mindepth` to get rid of the dot name inversion argument.)

Answer (score 3):

Go one level up and type in the directory name

```
rm -rf <dir>/*
```

Comment: If you already are in / and do
cd ..
rm -rf /*
You will get owned. ;)

Comment: use ALWAYS the directory name you want to delete! Never work as root.

Answer (score 3):

I use one of:

```
rm -fr .

cd ..; rm -fr name-of-subdirectory
```

I'm seldom sufficiently attached to a directory that I want to get rid of the contents but must keep the directory itself.

Comment: I'd even go as far and using "cd .. && rm -fr name-of-subdir" if for some insane reason the "cd .." should fail, you might delete the wrong directory (if it exists at both levels) - quite paranoid, isn't it ;-)

Comment: @Christian K: I would normally use two separate interactive commands rather than actually separating them with a semi-colon.  Your revision is safer.  There are times when 'cd ..' can fail; one is when someone has already removed the directory; another is when you don't have permission (any more).

Comment: @Christian K: If your shell supports it, then 'cd .. && rm -fr $OLDPWD' is pretty safe.  Using 'rm -fr ~-' would have dire consequences if you accidentally put a space between the tilde and the dash, so it is less safe.

Answer (score 2):

When using rm -rf I almost always use the fully qualified path.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`trash`](http://code.google.com/p/trash-cli/) command. In Debian/Ubuntu/etc., it can be installed from the package `trash-cli`. It works on both files and directories (since it's really moving the file, rather than immediately deleting it).

`trash` implements the [freedesktop.org trash specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec), compatible with the GNOME and KDE trash.

Files can be undeleted using `restore-trash` from the same package, or through the usual GUI.

Comment: Looks like the greatest answer to me.  Any drawback ?
The only thing I wonder is "how much time does it keep files ?", since of course, this could produce disk issues when you actually... try to delete files, which end up "quarantined"

Answer (score 0):

You could always turn on `-i` which would prompt you on every file, but that would be really time consuming for large directories.

I always do a `pwd` first.

I'll even go as far as to create an alias so that it forces the prompt for my users.  Red Hat does that by default, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the `f' switch and it should prompt you for each file to make sure you really want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to blow away an entire directory there is always some level of danger associated with that operation.  If you really want to be sure that you are doing the right thing you could always do a move operation to some place like /tmp, wait for some amount of time to make sure that everything is okay with the "deletion" in place.  Then go into the /tmp directory and ONLY use relative paths for a forced and recursive remove operation.  Additional, in the move do a rename to "delete-directoryname" to make it easier not to make a mistake.

For example I want to delete /opt/folder so I do:

mv /opt/folder /tmp/delete-folder

.... wait to be sure everything is okay - maybe a minute, maybe a week ....

cd /tmp

pwd

rm -rf delete-folder/

The most important tip for doing an rm -rf is to always use relative paths.  This keeps you from ever having typed a / before having completed your typing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason I have [tcsh]:

```
alias clean  '\rm -i -- "#"* *~'
alias rmo    'rm -- *.o'
```

They were created the first time I accidentally put a space between the * and the .o.  Suffice to say, what happened wasn't what I expected to happen...

But things could have been worse.  Back in the early '90s, a friend of mine had a **~/etc** directory.  He wanted to delete it.  Unfortunately he typed **rm -rf  /etc**.  Unfortunately, he was logged in as root.  He had a bad day!

---

To be evil: **touch -- '-rf *'**

To be safe, use **'--'** and **-i**.  Or get it right once and create an alias!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the alias I am using on macOS. It would ask for every rm command before executing.

```
# ~/.profile

function saferm() {
    echo rm "$@" 
    echo "" 
    read -p "* execute rm (y/n)? :  " yesorno

    if [ $yesorno == "y" ]; then
         /bin/rm "$@"
    fi
}

alias srm=saferm
alias rm=srm
```