# Safe rm -rf function in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, sed

This question is similar to [What is the safest way to empty a directory in *nix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373156/what-is-the-safest-way-to-empty-a-directory-in-nix)

I'm writing bash script which defines several path constants and will use them for file and directory manipulation (copying, renaming and deleting). Often it will be necessary to do something like:

```
rm -rf "/${PATH1}"
rm -rf "${PATH2}/"*
```

While developing this script I'd want to protect myself from mistyping names like PATH1 and PATH2 and avoid situations where they are expanded to empty string, thus resulting in wiping whole disk. I decided to create special wrapper:

```
rmrf() {
    if [[ $1 =~ "regex" ]]; then
        echo "Ignoring possibly unsafe path ${1}"
        exit 1
    fi

    shopt -s dotglob
    rm -rf -- $1
    shopt -u dotglob
}
```

Which will be called as:

```
rmrf "/${PATH1}"
rmrf "${PATH2}/"*
```

Regex (or sed expression) should catch paths like "*", "/*", "/**/", "///*" etc. but allow paths like "dir", "/dir", "/dir1/dir2/", "/dir1/dir2/*".  Also I don't know how to enable shell globbing in case like "/dir with space/*". Any ideas?

EDIT: this is what I came up with so far:

```
rmrf() {
    local RES
    local RMPATH="${1}"
    SAFE=$(echo "${RMPATH}" | sed -r 's:^((\.?\*+/+)+.*|(/+\.?\*+)+.*|[\.\*/]+|.*/\.\*+)$::g')
    if [ -z "${SAFE}" ]; then
        echo "ERROR! Unsafe deletion of ${RMPATH}"
        return 1
    fi

    shopt -s dotglob
    if [ '*' == "${RMPATH: -1}" ]; then
        echo rm -rf -- "${RMPATH/%\*/}"*
        RES=$?
    else
        echo rm -rf -- "${RMPATH}"
        RES=$?
    fi
    shopt -u dotglob

    return $RES
}
```

Intended use is (note an asterisk *inside* quotes):

```
rmrf "${SOMEPATH}"
rmrf "${SOMEPATH}/*"
```

where $SOMEPATH is not system or /home directory (in my case all such operations are performed on filesystem mounted under /scratch directory).

CAVEATS:

- not tested very well
- not intended to use with paths possibly containing '..' or '.'
- should not be used with user-supplied paths
- rm -rf with asterisk probably can fail if there are too many files or directories inside $SOMEPATH (because of limited command line length) - this can be fixed with 'for' loop or 'find' command

Answer (score 11):

I've found a big danger with rm in bash is that bash usually doesn't stop for errors. That means that:

```
cd $SOMEPATH
rm -rf *
```

Is a very dangerous combination if the change directory fails. A safer way would be:

```
cd $SOMEPATH && rm -rf *
```

Which will ensure the rf won't run unless you are really in $SOMEPATH. This doesn't protect you from a bad $SOMEPATH but it can be combined with the advice given by others to help make your script safer.

EDIT: @placeybordeaux makes a good point that if $SOMEPATH is undefined or empty `cd` doesn't treat it as an error and returns 0. In light of that this answer should be considered unsafe unless $SOMEPATH is validated as existing and non-empty first. I believe `cd` with no args should be an illegal command since at best is performs a no-op and at worse it can lead to unexpected behaviour but it is what it is.

Comment: If $SOMEPATH is empty won't this ```rm -rf``` the user's home directory?

Comment: @placeybordeaux The `&&` only runs the second command if the first succeeds - so if `cd` fails `rm` never runs

Comment: @SpliFF at least in ZSH the return value of  `cd $NONEXISTANTVAR`  is `0`

Comment: @placeybordeaux Good point. Since `cd` with no args is apparently a valid command.

Comment: Instead of `cd $SOMEPATH`, you should write `cd "${SOMEPATH?}"`. The `${varname?}` notation ensures that the expansion fails with a warning-message if the variable is unset or empty (such that the `&& ...` part is never run); the double-quotes ensure that special characters in `$SOMEPATH`, such as whitespace, don't have undesired effects.

Comment: `cd` with no args moves to your home dir. http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/cdh.html

Answer (score 5):

There is a `set -u` bash directive that will cause exit, when uninitialized variable is used. I read about it [here](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html), with `rm -rf` as an example. I think that's what you're looking for. And here is [set's manual](http://webtools.live2support.com/linux/set.php).

Answer (score 2):

I think "rm" command has a parameter to avoid the deleting of "/". Check it out.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about such option. Actually it is named --preserve-root and is not mentioned in the manpage.

Comment: On my system this option is on by default, but it cat't help in case like rm -ri /*

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend to use realpath(1) and not the command argument directly, so that you can avoid things like /A/B/../ or symbolic links.

Comment: Useful but non-standard command. I've found possible bash replacement: http://www.archlinux.org/pipermail/pacman-dev/2009-February/008130.html

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when I'm developing a command with operations such as '`rm -fr`' in it, I will neutralize the remove during development.  One way of doing that is:

```
RMRF="echo rm -rf"
...
$RMRF "/${PATH1}"
```

This shows me what should be deleted - but does not delete it.  I will do a manual clean up while things are under development - it is a small price to pay for not running the risk of screwing up everything.

The notation '`"/${PATH1}"`' is a little unusual; normally, you would ensure that PATH1 simply contains an absolute pathname.

Using the metacharacter with '`"${PATH2}/"*`' is unwise and unnecessary.  The only difference between using that and using just '`"${PATH2}"`' is that if the directory specified by PATH2 contains any files or directories with names starting with dot, then those files or directories will not be removed.  Such a design is unlikely and is rather fragile.  It would be much simpler just to pass PATH2 and let the recursive remove do its job.  Adding the trailing slash is not necessarily a bad idea; the system would have to ensure that `$PATH2` contains a directory name, not just a file name, but the extra protection is rather minimal.

Using globbing with '`rm -fr`' is usually a bad idea.  You want to be precise and restrictive and limiting in what it does - to prevent accidents.  Of course, you'd never run the command (shell script you are developing) as root while it is under development - that would be suicidal.  Or, if root privileges are absolutely necessary, you neutralize the remove operation until you are confident it is bullet-proof.

Comment: To delete subdirectories and files starting with dot I use "shopt -s dotglob".  Using rm -rf "${PATH2}" is not appropriate because in my case PATH2 can be only removed by superuser and this results in error status for "rm" command (and I verify it to track other errors).

Comment: Then, with due respect, you should use a private sub-directory under $PATH2 that you can remove. Avoid glob expansion with commands like 'rm -rf' like you would avoid the plague (or should that be A/H1N1?).

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
set -f    # cf. help set
```

to disable filename generation (*).

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I've found this perl project: http://code.google.com/p/safe-rm/

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible, you should try and put everything into a folder with a hard-coded name which is unlikely to be found anywhere else on the filesystem, such as '`foofolder`'. Then you can write your `rmrf()` function as:

```
rmrf() {
    rm -rf "foofolder/$PATH1"
    # or
    rm -rf "$PATH1/foofolder"
}
```

There is no way that function can delete anything but the files you want it to.

Comment: Actually there is a way: if `PATH1` is something like `../../someotherdir`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regular expressions.
Just assign the directories you want to protect to a variable and then iterate over the variable.  eg:

```
protected_dirs="/ /bin /usr/bin /home $HOME"
for d in $protected_dirs; do
    if [ "$1" = "$d" ]; then
        rm=0
        break;
    fi
done
if [ ${rm:-1} -eq 1 ]; then
    rm -rf $1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following codes to your `~/.bashrc`

```
# safe delete
move_to_trash () { now="$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"; mv "$@" ~/.local/share/Trash/files/"$@_$now"; }
alias del='move_to_trash'

# safe rm
alias rmi='rm -i'
```

Every time you need to `rm` something, first consider `del`, you can change the trash folder. If you do need to `rm` something, you could go to the trash folder and use `rmi`.

One small bug for `del` is that when `del` a folder, for example, `my_folder`, it should be `del my_folder` but not `del my_folder/` since in order for possible later restore, I attach the time information in the end (`"$@_$now"`). For files, it works fine.